# Ruby assign more than one arguments from terminal

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal, arguments, argv

I'm using the terminal and assigning multiple variables on a ruby file hello_world.rb in the following way:

```
$ ruby hello_world.rb arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

If I put

```
$ ruby hello_world.rb hello world mars jupiter
```

I need it to display

```
hello world
hello mars 
hello jupiter
```

And if I put

```
$ ruby hello_World.rb whaddup boy girl
```

it needs to display

```
whaddup boy
whaddup girl
```

1st argument will be the first string, and the rest of the arguments will each be listed as 2nd string.

I was able to create the code:

```
def hello_world(first, *second)
    second.each do |arg|
        puts "#{first} #{arg}"
    end
end
```

But when I run `$ ruby hello_world.rb hello world mars` from terminal, it would not display anything. I think I have to use ARGV. I know how to do with only one argument,

```
def hello_world
    ARGV.each do |arg|
        puts "Hello #{arg}"
    end
end

hello_world
```

Terminal:

```
$ ruby hello_world.rb world mars jupiter
#=> Hello world
#=> Hello mars
#=> Hello jupiter
```

I have no idea how to do it in case of two arguments or more. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ARGV` constant is just an array, so you can do the following, for example:

```
def hello_world
  first = ARGV.shift
  puts ARGV.map { |arg| "#{first} #{arg}" }
end

hello_world
```

The method `Array#shift` will remove and return the first element of an array. In this case the first argument passed from the command line.

Output:

```
$ ruby hello_world.rb hello world mars
#=> hello world
#=> hello mars
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use your first `hello_world` method, but invoke it with the elements of ARGV, not ARGV itself, with a splat:

```
def hello_world(first, *second)
    second.each do |arg|
        puts "#{first} #{arg}"
    end
end

hello_world *ARGV
# ..........^
```

Documented at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion